# Appcelerator & Facebook FQL Multiquery

Tags: facebook, appcelerator, facebook-fql

how can I use multiquery Facebook FQL with Appcelerator?

Titanium.Facebook.request('fql.query', {query: query}, function(r) ..

doesn't work. :(

This is the example that doesn't work:
...

var query = {"query1":"SELECT pid FROM photo_tag WHERE subject="+ Titanium.Facebook.uid,"query2":"SELECT pid FROM photo_tag WHERE subject="+friendUid+" AND pid IN (SELECT pid FROM #query1)","query3":"SELECT src_big FROM photo WHERE pid IN (SELECT pid FROM #query2)"};

Titanium.Facebook.request('fql.query', query,  function(r)

...

Thanks, Stefano

Comment: yes it does work.. can you post your example that is not working?

Comment: var query = {"query1":"SELECT pid FROM photo_tag WHERE subject="+ Titanium.Facebook.uid,"query2":"SELECT pid FROM photo_tag WHERE subject="+friendUid+" AND pid IN (SELECT pid FROM #query1)","query3":"SELECT src_big FROM photo WHERE pid IN (SELECT pid FROM #query2)"};
 

 Titanium.Facebook.request('fql.query', query,  function(r)

Answer (score 0):

I think your best approach might be to just make the call using the httpClient and call the facebook API directly

Comment: Thanks Aaron, could you give me an example please?